# zend framework 2 import module js

Tags: module, zend-framework2

I don't know how to import one file javascript in my new module Zend Framework 2.

The code is located in: vendor\name-module\js\test.js

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
$this->headScript()->prependFile('../../vendor/name-module/js/test.js');
```

`../` goes back to public `../../` goes to the main application

make sure to `echo $this->headScript();` in a layout or view

If you want to use use a javaScript file per controller use it like this:

```
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

...

public function indexAction()
{
    $headScript = new PhpRenderer();
    $headScript->headScript()->appendFile('../../vendor/name-module/js/test.js');
}
```

edit:

u can use the `public` folder. make a folder called `js` and put the JavaScript files there, then use:

```
$headScript->headScript()->appendFile('/js/test.js');
```

Comment: i will test, but i think is not a good solution, if tomorow the name "vendor" change to "library", all places i will need to change to "library", understand?

Comment: the `public` folder is there for that reason. place your files in the `public` folder